# Issue with apache service, mamp, .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, mamp

I am building the android app which is connected, well, has an adminpanel.
So I have a problem to enter in that adminpanel website. So I have installed mamp, apache and mysql are working, have extract html files of adminpanel to the htdocs of apache files. The problem is when I am opening the web site, it does open first page, when it asks me for user and pass, and that is all ok, but then when pressing enter, its showing this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /nameofproject/Admin/login was not found on this server.
```

I have tried a lots of solutions, but still havent found the problem, is it maybe some code in .htcaccess that has to be change? 
This is the .htcaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thank you on your time and help.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an android question, unless the problem only occurs from android and not from a desktop browser.

Comment: yes, you are right, will remove android tag